# How to fix 'Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 168, 5)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to implement a multiple input LSTM-DNN hybrid model where the output of both layers are concatenated. Unfortunately right after initiating training this happens:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 168, 5)
```

I have researched other methods but most concern the case when the got array has a smaller dimension than the expected. I have read that flatten might be helpful but I'm not certain how to implement it.

This is my model:

```
# first input model
input_1 = Input(shape=(5, ))
input_1_expand = tf.expand_dims(input_1, axis=-1) 
dense_1 = Dense(units=64, input_shape=(None, 5,))(input_1_expand)

# second input model
input_2 = Input(shape=(7, ))
input_2_expand = tf.expand_dims(input_2, axis=-1)
lstm_1 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 7,))(input_2_expand)

# merge input models
merge = concatenate([dense_1, lstm_1], axis=1)
output = Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid')(merge)
model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=output)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

The model training:

```
%time
model.fit_generator(generator=generator,
                    epochs=10,
                    steps_per_epoch=30,
                    validation_data=validation_data,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Where generator is a batch_generator function that yields

```
 [x_batch_1, x_batch_2], y_batch
```

```
x_batch_1 shape: (32, 168, 5)
x_batch_2 shape: (32, 168, 7)
y_batch shape: (32, 168, 1)
```

Where 32 is the batch size and 168 is the sequence length

I am also not sure with how I implemented tf.expand and concatenate axis. I just tried the combination that would make the model compile

EDIT:
I forgot to include the validation_data:

```
validation_data = ([np.expand_dims(x_test1_scaled, axis=0),
                    np.expand_dims(x_test2_scaled, axis=0)],
                   np.expand_dims(y_test_scaled, axis=0))
```

Where

```
expanded x_test1_scaled Shape: (1, 5808, 5)
expanded x_test2_scaled Shape: (1, 5808, 7)
expanded y_test_scaled Shape: (1, 5808, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `sequencr length` in the input shape too, shape must be the same as `x_batch.shape[1:]`

Like this

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(168, 5, ))
dense_1 = Dense(units=64, input_shape=(None, 5,))(input_1)

input_2 = Input(shape=(168, 7, ))
lstm_1 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 7,))(input_2)
```

I suppose you tried to use `expand_dims` to fix this so I don't include that.

Comment: BTW if you edit your pose you should inform answerer in comment too, it won't notify otherwise.

Comment: I have updated the post to include information regarding the validation_data. I've tried your post (removed the expand_dims, and the axis in concatenate), I've also replaced the 168 with None to allow for variable inputs and it trains! Thank you.

Comment: If you mean by you want to use the `validation_data` which is 5808 instead of 168, this might not work though. You need to make them the same because `Dense` and `LSTM` need to have the input shape specific.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by making them the same? Doesn't None allow for variable sizes though? I've changed 168 to None for both input_1 and input_2 and it does train.

Comment: Really? I thought `Dense` layer need input shape to be exact number and cannot be changed but I probably wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your input_1 and input_2 sample got 1 dimension which make the training input_1 or input_2 only 2 dimensions but your generator have 3 dimensions for each of them.

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(5, ))

input_2 = Input(shape=(7, ))
```